# SQL Server, query using right index but still slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT 1
FROM [Call]
INNER JOIN [Caller] ON [Call].callerId = [Caller].id
WHERE [Call].[phoneNumber] = @phoneNumber
AND
[Caller].callerType = @callerType
AND
[Call].[time] > @time
AND
[Call].[status] = @status
AND
[Call].[type] <> @type
```

There is a clustered primary key index on `[Caller]` `id` column.  There is a non-clustered index on `[Call]` as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_callerId_time_phonenumber_status_type 
ON dbo.[Call]
(
    [callerId] ASC,
    [time] ASC,
    [phoneNumber] ASC,
    [status] ASC,
    [type] ASC
)
```

I notice in the execution plan that 90% of the cost of my query is as follows:

```
Predicate:
[Call].[status] = 10 AND [Call].[type] <> 10

Object:
[Call].[IX_callerId_time_phonenumber_status_type]
```

So it's using the right index but I'm still getting bad performance.  Any ideas?

Comment: That is an index scan right? Your inequality in the predicate potentially renders the predicate nonSARGable. Simply changing to call.type >10 OR call.type < 10 would probably make that a seek instead.

Comment: Only `time` column is used to traverse the tree. There is nothing that narrows the traversal down - everything later is just a filter predicate. You should almost always index by equality first, not by ranges.

Comment: @SeanLange it's actually a seek already.

Comment: @SeanLange, I changed it to less than or greater than but it got compiled back to != according to the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Predicate `[Call].[time] > @time` is fairly unselective, but the structure of your index forces SQL Server to give it priority over some other criteria that are probably more selective.  It likely chooses to scan a big chunk of the index for each `callerId`.  Reordering the index like so would probably improve performance for this particular query:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_callerId_time_phonenumber_status_type 
ON dbo.[Call]
(
    [callerId] ASC,
    [phoneNumber] ASC,
    [status] ASC,
    [time] ASC,
    [type] ASC
)
```

Comment: this table has over 100 million rows going back 10 years, so I thought time should be higher in priority especially since the queries are mostly querying recent data.  Given that, what do you think the index should look like?

Comment: @ghettojoe, it is probably worthwhile to try it both ways.  If I had to guess, though, then I'd still put my money on the order I suggested.  It should end up scanning many fewer rows of the index, but that will be mitigated by those rows being more widely scattered.  Note, too, that I'm speaking only to the effect on *this* query.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing if "Time" is really a Time datatype or a varchar datatype, I would suggest the following index.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_callerId_time_phonenumber_status_type
ON [dbo].[Call] ([PhoneNumber],[Status],[Time],[Type])
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ruled out parameter sniffing? Wondering if the optimizer is stuck on some not-good-for-the-values.

This is my fav article http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/

Comment: Another link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/turgays/archive/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-workarounds.aspx